# What is the good way of using lookup table in business logic?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, domain-driven-design, lookup-tables

I was asked to use a table to store status of an entity type. Normally I used always enums for that before.

There is a business logic in which the status of the entity changing. This logic is encapsulated in the entity. It was easy when the status was an enum type. But now I would need to inject a service to get the required status. I do not know if it is a good idea to inject a service (like StatusService) into that method making the method depend on IStatusService.

Example code:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public MyEntityStatus Status { set; get; }

    public void MethodInWhichStatusMayChange(IMyEntityStatusService myEntityStatusService)
    {
        //using myEntityStatusService to get the status when it should change
    }
}

public class MyEntityStatus
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
}

public interface IMyEntityStatusService
{
    MyEntityStatus GetStatusA();
    MyEntityStatus GetStatusB();
    MyEntityStatus GetStatusC();
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `MyEntityStatus` class? It doesn't have any methods or abstraction. It isn't very useful IMHO.

Comment: The point is that people working on the database side do not have to take a look at my enum values and data integrity is better also.

Comment: What about code generation? Just generate enums based on database values. As long as statuses aren't added dynamically that's a great strategy.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to inject the service in the class constructor:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    private readonly IMyEntityStatusService myEntityStatusService;

    public MyEntity(IMyEntityStatusService myEntityStatusService)
    {
        this.myEntityStatusService = myEntityStatusService;
    }

    public MyEntityStatus Status { set; get; }

    public void MethodInWhichStatusMayChange()
    {
        //now you use the private myEntityStatusService field
    }
}
```

This will make your life easier if you decide to use a dependency injection engine, and also your code will be cleaner, easier to use (you don't have to be passing around instances of `IMyEntityStatusService`), and as pointed out in the comments, easier to test.

Comment: And the most important thing - it will be testable and easy to perform unit tests with  :)

Comment: @RanSasportas What makes it untestable if you use method injection?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Method injection is testable too, but constructor injection is easier to test because it's a pattern that most testing frameworks support out of the box.

Comment: @jannagy02 Another option is to use "factory pattern". Just one method to create status parameterized with some enum. `CreateStatus(EntityStatusEnumType)`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Does it give me any benefit? The factory should depend on the service in this case.

Comment: The whole effort to encapsulate state changes become kind of a joke with that public setter there. Any reason why you put it there?